# How to select a random piece of data in a pool of data in a database using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, list, random, syntax

I have created two tables, one to store person, and the other to store 5 numbers they've selected. Now, each person can input any number of their liking, and their row of five numbers correspond with their personid. My goal is to create code that will select a random number from a pool of numbers of let's say, 4 people.

```sql
Person
    personid(PRIMARY KEY)
    name

numberlist
    numid(PRIMARY KEY)
    personid(FOREIGN KEY)
    num1
    num2
    num3
    num4
    num5
```

I have the following query:

```sql
    SELECT num1,num2,num3,num4,num5 
    FROM Project.numberlist
    ORDER BY RAND ()
    LIMIT 1
```

The code works but it would output a random row. An example output is:

```
[(12, 15, 23, 54, 7)]
```

How would I design the query so that it would output only one number? For this example, it would randomly output one number like 23 or 15 instead of the whole row.

Comment: Start by fixing your schema, such that you're selecting a random row, not a random column

Comment: So would that mean I'd have to create three tables instead of two?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could still have two tables, but your second table would be normalised (e.g. `id,num_id,person_id,val`), where id is PRIMARY, and (num_id,person_id) is UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "unpivoting" your 5 number columns so they form one column: e.g.

```
SELECT num1 as num FROM Project.numberlist union all
SELECT num2 as num FROM Project.numberlist union all
SELECT num3 as num FROM Project.numberlist union all
SELECT num4 as num FROM Project.numberlist union all
SELECT num5 as num FROM Project.numberlist
ORDER BY RAND ()
LIMIT 1
```

Consider normalising your data model so that you can avoid these workarounds.